# Creating a comma-separated list of space-separated lists — erroneus append() behavior

Tags: sass

I would like to create a comma-separated list of space-separated lists.

I expect to get the following meta-list: `( (1 2), (3 4) )`.

I can't use a literal because the meta list should be assembled out of existing lists stored in variables. So i use `append()`.

My problem is that `append()` breaks the first list, producing `( 1, 2, (3 4) )`.

```
$meta-list: append( ((1 2)), (3 4), comma)
@warn $meta-list
// WARNING: 1, 2, 3 4

@warn nth($meta-list, 1)
// WARNING: 1

// Just to make sure:
@warn @warn nth( ( (1 2), (3 4) ), 1)
//WARNING: 1 2
```

Why does this happen and how ot assemble a meta list correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i got it.

The solution is to create a blank list first.

```
$meta-list: ()
$meta-list: append( $meta-list, (1 2), comma)
$meta-list: append( $meta-list, (3 4), comma)

@warn $meta-list
// WARNING: 1 2, 3 4

@warn nth($meta-list, 1)
// WARNING: 1 2
```