# Remove items from list in SCSS but preserve commas

Tags: sass

I am trying to remove "textarea" from this list from Bourbon:

```
$text-inputs-list: 'input[type="color"]',
                   'input[type="date"]',
                   'input[type="datetime"]',
                   'input[type="datetime-local"]',
                   'input[type="email"]',
                   'input[type="month"]',
                   'input[type="number"]',
                   'input[type="password"]',
                   'input[type="search"]',
                   'input[type="tel"]',
                   'input[type="text"]',
                   'input[type="time"]',
                   'input[type="url"]',
                   'input[type="week"]',
                   'input:not([type])',
                   'textarea';

$all-text-inputs:        assign-inputs($text-inputs-list);
```

BTW, `assign-inputs` looks like this:

```
@function _assign-inputs(
    $inputs,
    $pseudo: null
  ) {

  $list: ();

  @each $input in $inputs {
    $input: unquote($input);
    $input: if($pseudo, $input + ":" + $pseudo, $input);
    $list: append($list, $input, comma);
  }

  @return $list;
}
```

I found the following function for removing items from here: http://hugogiraudel.com/2013/08/08/advanced-sass-list-functions/

```
@function remove($list, $value, $recursive: false) {
  $result: ();

  @for $i from 1 through length($list) {
    @if type-of(nth($list, $i)) == list and $recursive {
      $result: append($result, remove(nth($list, $i), $value, $recursive));
    }

    @else if nth($list, $i) != $value {
      $result: append($result, nth($list, $i));
    }
  }

  @return $result;
}
```

So I remove the "textarea" item like this:

```
$all-text-inputs-except-textarea: remove($all-text-inputs, 'textarea');
```

Normally I'd use `$all-text-inputs` like this:

```
#{$all-text-inputs} {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

And that would expand out to:

```
input[type="email"], input[type="password"], ... {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

But when I use `$all-text-inputs-except-textarea` in the same way:

```
#{$all-text-inputs-except-textarea} {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

It instead expands out to:

```
input[type="email"] input[type="password"] ... {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

Note the lack of comma delimiters. It turns into one big nested child selector.

I have managed to avoid the issue with this function:

```
@function comma-delimit($list) {
  $result: ();
  @each $item in $list {
    $result: append($result, $item, comma);
  }
  @return $result;
}
```

And then I do:

```
$all-text-inputs-except-textarea: comma-delimit(remove($all-text-inputs, 'textarea'));
```

And then `$all-text-inputs-except-textarea` has commas, just like its predecessor.

Although, it feels like a workaround. Isn't there any way to remove items from a list, but preserve commas in the list if there are any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining knowledge from [the article you provided](http://hugogiraudel.com/2013/07/15/understanding-sass-lists/) with knowledge from [Creating a comma-separated list of space-separated lists — erroneus append() behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15854029/creating-a-comma-separated-list-of-space-separated-lists-erroneus-append-beh), I was able to modify your `remove` function like so:

```
@function remove($list, $value, $recursive: false) {
  $result: ();

  @for $i from 1 through length($list) {
    @if type-of(nth($list, $i)) == list and $recursive {
      $result: append($result, remove(nth($list, $i), $value, $recursive));
    }

    @else if nth($list, $i) != $value {
      $result: append($result, nth($list, $i), comma);
    }
  }

  @return $result;
}

$all-text-inputs-except-textarea: remove($all-text-inputs, 'textarea');

#{$all-text-inputs-except-textarea} {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

(note the `comma` keyword as the extra argument to the base case in `remove()`)

The above produces the output you desire.

```
input[type="color"], input[type="date"], input[type="datetime"], input[type="datetime-local"], input[type="email"], input[type="month"], input[type="number"], input[type="password"], input[type="search"], input[type="tel"], input[type="text"], input[type="time"], input[type="url"], input[type="week"], input:not([type]) {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

I created [a gist of the code](https://gist.github.com/caleb531/a2b0f0fa3b6adac50c215a49ece6b045) which you can [run on SassMeister](http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/a2b0f0fa3b6adac50c215a49ece6b045).

Answer (score 0):

Caleb's answer worked well in my particular scenario. To generalize his solution slightly, I wanted to ensure that, additionally, space-separated lists would still be separated by spaces after an item was removed. For this, I used `list_separator` instead of the `comma` constant:

```
$result: append($result, nth($list, $i), list_separator($list));
```

So the final function became:

```
@function remove($list, $value, $recursive: false) {
  $result: ();

  @for $i from 1 through length($list) {
    @if type-of(nth($list, $i)) == list and $recursive {
      $result: append($result, remove(nth($list, $i), $value, $recursive));
    }

    @else if nth($list, $i) != $value {
      $result: append($result, nth($list, $i), list_separator($list));
    }
  }

  @return $result;
}
```